# How to retrieve form data from Playwright Request object?

Tags: python, multipartform-data, playwright, playwright-python

I am adding a custom route handler to a Playwright page and I am trying to inspect the request passed into the handler. For context here is a following code snippet:

```py
def handler(route: Route, request: Request):
    # Do things with `request`
    ...

await page.route('**/*', handler=handler)
```

For `POST`/`PUT` requests with a `Content-Type` of `application/json`, I have been able to successfully inspect the payload by using `request.post_data_buffer`. However, when the `Content-Type` is `multipart/form-data`, I have not been able locate where I can get the form data. All of the `post_data`, `post_data_buffer`, and `post_data_json` properties have a value of `None`, and I couldn't see anything else in the documentation which could contain the `form_data`.

Comment: `post_data` should return the data if the request has it, if it's not there it's worth filing a bug with a repro at https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python

Comment: @YurySemikhatsky I opened up an issue: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python/issues/1064, thanks for your recommendation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had nothing to do with really any details in my original post. The issue was I was using Chromium, and it is a [known bug](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/6479) that `post_data` does not contain file/blob data.